# Perform computational operations on arrays and difficulty displaying output

Tags: javascript

```js
let menu = [
    { id: 1, name: "Soda", price: 3.12, size: "4oz", type: "Drink" },
    { id: 2, name: "Beer", price: 6.50, size: "8oz", type: "Drink" },
    { id: 3, name: "Margarita", price: 12.99, size: "12oz", type: "Drink" },
    { id: 4, name: "Pizza", price: 25.10, size: "60oz", type: "Food" },
    { id: 5, name: "Kebab", price: 31.48, size: "42oz", type: "Food" },
    { id: 6, name: "Berger", price: 23.83, size: "99oz", type: "Food" },
];

const usa_menu = () => {
    const usaPrice = 1.8;
    const usaSize = 2;
    const getNumber = menu.map(item => parseFloat(item.size));
    const newSize = getNumber.reduce((item) => item.size * usaSize);
    const getPrice = menu.map(item => item.price);
    const newPrice = getPrice.reduce((item) => item.size * usaPrice);
    console.log(`id : ${item.id} , name : ${item.name} , price: ${newPrice} , size: ${newSize}oz , type: ${item.type}`)
};
usa_menu();
```

I have an array that is a food menu. I want the size of the food to be multiplied by 2 and their price to be 1.8, and show it like the result I gave below, but there is a problem that the code does not work.

Comment: Could you share `menu` in a minimal reproducible example? It's an array, isn't it?

Comment: What specifically doesn’t work?

Comment: @Miu yes I added it in the form of an array

Comment: @Miu i want to show me the new menu again after increasing the price and increasing the size

Comment: Thank you for the update. What is your expected output?

Comment: @Miu I want my menu list to multiply the size of the food by 2 and the price multiplied by 1.8 and show the rest with the same name and specifications as the top array, but the size and price change and show the new menu

Comment: Do you want to make a new array with new prices, new sizes and the rest? Or change the original array `menu`?

Comment: @Miu Yes I want to show new array with new price and size I do not want to change old array only new array with price and size

Comment: I got it. I'm gonna try :) Just a moment plz

Comment: @Miu Thanks dear friend for the help :)

Comment: @Dave Newton can you help me?

Comment: I could, but I believe you can figure this out on your own. I don’t see any reason for `reduce` here at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like `.forEach()` answer as well. Here is a solution with `for loop`.

```js
let menu = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Soda",
    price: 3.12,
    size: "4oz",
    type: "Drink"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Beer",
    price: 6.50,
    size: "8oz",
    type: "Drink"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Margarita",
    price: 12.99,
    size: "12oz",
    type: "Drink"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Pizza",
    price: 25.10,
    size: "60oz",
    type: "Food"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "Kebab",
    price: 31.48,
    size: "42oz",
    type: "Food"
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: "Berger",
    price: 23.83,
    size: "99oz",
    type: "Food"
  },
];

const usa_menu = (arr) => {
  const usaPrice = 1.8;
  const usaSize = 2;

  // Make a copy of 'menu'
  const newMenu = [...arr];

  // Change prices and sizes
  for (const item of newMenu) {
    // Multiply a price by 1.8 and round it off
    item.price = Math.round(item.price * usaPrice * 100) / 100;
    // Multiply a size by 2
    item.size = parseInt(item.size) * usaSize;
  }

  return newMenu;
};

console.log(usa_menu(menu));
```

Comment: I have updated the `for` loop part of my code. Either is okay. I prefer `for ... of` to `for` because it's simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.forEach()` like so:

```js
let menu = [
    { id: 1, name: "Soda", price: 3.12, size: "4oz", type: "Drink" },
    { id: 2, name: "Beer", price: 6.50, size: "8oz", type: "Drink" },
    { id: 3, name: "Margarita", price: 12.99, size: "12oz", type: "Drink" },
    { id: 4, name: "Pizza", price: 25.10, size: "60oz", type: "Food" },
    { id: 5, name: "Kebab", price: 31.48, size: "42oz", type: "Food" },
    { id: 6, name: "Berger", price: 23.83, size: "99oz", type: "Food" },
];

menu.forEach(item => console.log(`id : ${item.id} , name : ${item.name} , price: ${(item.price * 1.8).toFixed(2)} , size: ${parseInt(item.size) * 2}oz , type: ${item.type}`));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Hi! I like this approach with `.forEach()` :) But be careful, it seems that this does not create a new array but just displays the results in the console.

Comment: I know it doesn't, in the example th OP didn't try to return anything so I guess just printing the result is fine